# Names for a chatroom?

Tags: discussion, chat

Our chatroom is currently called [Robotics](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6221/robotics). It's not really necessary, but it's be quite nice to have a more fun name. For example, Programmers has "The Whiteboard", Chemistry has "The Periodic Table", SU has "Root Access", and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

<strike>As a slightly left field suggestion, and</strike> in deference to (one of) the fathers of fictional robotics - not to mention the creator of the [Three Laws of Robotics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_Laws_of_Robotics):

Asimov's Corner?

Comment: That's hardly left field at all!

Comment: I've renamed the chatroom for now, enjoy!

Comment: Thanks... I approve :)

Answer (score 2):

[image: Skynet]

...uh oh

Comment: This is actually the name of the mod chat room for this site. :P

Answer (score 1):

The bus.

(Ignore this sentence, it's just to fill up my 30 character minimum)

Answer (score -2):

1. Chatbot
2. Artificial Unintelligence
3. i'mNotARobot (a somewhat weak pun on *I, Robot* and iRobot)?
4. Unmanned Chat Vehicle
5. Gearheads
6. Double (or some other telepresence robot reference)